# TCPDF not render tabs space with <pre> tag

Tags: tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to render a simple HTML that mainly have the data between "pre" tag. All is fine except when I have text separated by tabs spaces. Then the text is misaligned and don't show the text aligned.

I'm testing the first sample code.
https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_001/

Then I replace:

```
$html = <<<EOD
<pre>
RESEARCH LIST
XX-Name:            Notes: 
10-Progress         Get +20
20-Research         Get +2
27-Advanced Research        Get +5
28-Atmospheric Converters   Terraforming +1
29-Comet Ds     Terraforming +4
</pre>
EOD;
```

I get the PDF but the text isn't aligned with columns.

If I open as .html is aligned correctly.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>XYZ</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<body>
<PRE>
DC-Name:            Notes: 
10-Progress         Get +20
20-Research         Get +2
27-Advanced Research        Get +5
28-Atmospheric Converters   Terraforming +1
29-Comet Ds         Terraforming +4 
</PRE>
</body>
</HTML>
```

What is wrong?

Salut,
Josep M

Comment: using `<table></table>` if you want the best result

Comment: I can't convert it, I have too many pages, all with "pre" tag.

Comment: Seems an issue with tab character, so ist replaced each tab for one space, and don't see why.

Comment: Any help about why this happen?

Comment: I don't know why, but don't work. Anybody have experience with this issue with PRE tag?